# Azure search - keyword analyzer

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have document with below fields:

```
a_number_collection = { "AA BB", "DD FF" }
b_number_collection = { "AG BB", "AA F1" }
description = "sample super product"
```

What I would like to achive is to match document only if user will type in a whole number. The problem is that user have only single input for search query and can type for example "super AA BB product". I thought about keyword analyzer but the issue is that I don't know on which place in search query user put the number, so I can't search like "super \"AA BB\" product". Without keyword even with searchMode "all" I will get result for search query like "super AA AG product"

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Are the "numbers" in any particular pattern? Please take a look at custom analysis components that detect and replace patterns in text. PatternReplaceCharFilter with the regex pattern `([A-Z0-9]{2})\s([A-Z0-9]{2})` and the replacement=`"$1_$2"`. Given an input string `"hello AA BB world"`, the tokenfilter will analyze it the token sequence `<hello> <AA_BB> <world>` and search will return documents that match the whole "numbers" (eg AA_BB).

Hope this helps.